# Parent(Customer) and Child(Order) entity tables are created in MySql database but can't see the records on those tables

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have created Parent(Customer) and Child(Order)entity tables in the MySql database using hibernate and I have created one customer and some orders in those tables I can see those tables data in MySQL using MySql 8.0 command-line client but can't see on the database.

Could you please help me with the query?

[image: 8.0 command-line client]

[image]

Comment: have you executed `select * from orders`?

Comment: yes in the command line client.

Comment: MySQL Command Line is just a client to connect to the database, just like the MySQL Workbench of your print screen. If you need to see the data on the MySQL Workbench, you have two options: 1 - execute the select statement inside the editor, OR 2 - right-click on the table name on the left-side panel and click 'Select Rows'

Comment: Now I got it thank you Matheus.